# How to connect wires between power supply and switch?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, wiring, socket

I'm trying to connect non-fused and European AC power socket/toggle switch to power supply. Probably very "newbie" question but as a starter I didn't want to try-fail with this thing for safety reasons and decided to ask.

I found several wiring diagrams for different types of sockets but couldn't find exact same one with my parts.

Here is my parts on image, how can I connect these properly and safely?

[image: my parts]

Comment: if L is not connected to 1 or 0, use a meter to check, then connect L to 0 and 1 to L2. And G2-E and N to N2...

Comment: @dandavis I think it's not? Is it possible to have "internal" connection under the plastics? Or should I make a decision here to connect L to 1 or 0? I will connect a 3-pin power cable.

Comment: In addition to @dandavis connect N with N2, and E with G2 (last ohne is most important for securtiy reason)

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure they aren't connected, but better safe than sorry since checking is cheap and easy. Or just assume, and stand back when plugging it in and powering up for the first time, that's what I do when i'm "feeling lucky".

Comment: Please note that if the wall socket has Live and Neutral swapped, or if the mains plug can be connected two ways to the mains socket, you can end up switching Neutral, and Live goes directly to PSU. If there is a possibility to connect the mains plug to ungrounded mains socket, the Live will be connected to metal case via EMI filter Y capacitor. I found out this the hard way when I was repairing equipment and the power strip had a switch that cut only one wire, while they usually cut both. Only safe way is to use a switch that breaks both Live and Neutral, when using non-polar mains plugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you want to end up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDPNlX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In your image, you would take a short wire from L on the back of the plug to the "I" (or "O") on the switch, then from the other side of the switch to "L" on the power supply. The remaining N and G wires run straight through.

E (Earth) == G (Ground) 
N = Neutral 
L = Line

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG7wkq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Wiring the switched socket to a load.*